# Simple way to find determinant of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Consider the $(m-1)\times (m-1)$ matrix $M$ shown below.
  $$ M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1/2 & 1/2 & \ldots & 1/2\\
   1/2 & 1 & 1/2 & \ldots & 1/2\\
\vdots \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & \dots & 1
  \end{array} } \right]$$

I would like to show that $\det (M)=\frac{m}{2^{m-1}}$. I have tried induction, but the computation gets rather messy. When $m=2$, $\det(M)=1=2/2$, and when $m=2$, $\det(M)=1-1/2^2=3/2^2$.

I know some people are very good at seeing tricks to compute the determinant of a matrix like this without induction. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Add all the rows to the last one. You can take out the common factor and you'll get a row with all 1/2. You can substract it from every other row to get a diagonal matrix

Comment: 1. Build an (m-1)-dimensional parallelipiped with a vertex at (0,...0) and vertices at all the given columns and their sums.  2. Fill the parallelipiped with (m-1)-dimensional water.  3. Measure how much water it took.  You know, for fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. We know that $\frac12$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity at least $m-2$, because $M - \frac12I$ has rank $1$. In addition, the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of $M$, which is $m-1$. So if $x$ is the remaining eigenvalue, then $x + \frac12(m-2) = m-1$, which means that $x = \frac m2$.

Taking the product of the eigenvalues, we get $\frac m2 \cdot \left(\frac12\right)^{m-2} = \frac{m}{2^{m-1}}$.

---

Also, [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity) applies to $2$ times this matrix. If $\mathbf u$ is the vector of all $1$'s, then $2M = I + \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T$, so $\det(2M) = \det(I + \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T) = 1 + \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{u} = m$. Therefore $\det(M) = \frac1{2^{m-1}} \det(2M) = \frac{m}{2^{m-1}}$.

Comment: Or - by inspection, $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\frac{1}{2}(m-2) + 1 = \frac{m}{2}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you! Just a quick question...why does $M-\frac{1}{2}I$ having rank 1 imply that $1/2$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ with multiplicity at least $m-2$? Are you using the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem? Sorry, my linear algebra is a bit rusty...

Comment: In linear algebra, the geometric multiplicity--which is the dimension of the eigenspace--of an eigenvalue a is the nullspace of $(M-aI)$.  So since the matrix in question is rank 1 which is $m-2$ smaller than full rank, the nullspace is $(m-2)$ dimensional.  Then, the algebraic multiplicity of $a$, which is the exponent of $a$ in det(M) or the exponent of (a - lambda) in det(M-lambda I), is always at least the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: For matrices of this form I always take the difference of diagonal to off-diagonal for the main eigenvalue, as Misha did here, and then I use [1,1,...1] as an eigenvector to find the remaining eigenvalue (i.e. the sum of entries in any row), as Daniel did.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, consider the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
M(a)=\begin{bmatrix}
a & a & a & \dots & a \\
a & a & a & \dots & a \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \dots & \vdots \\
a & a & a & \dots & a
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $M(a)$ is
$$
\det(M(a)-XI)=(0-X)^{n-1}(na-X)
$$
Can you see why?

What value can you give to $X$ in order to have your given matrix?